# HTML страница не выводит кириллицу

Tags: html, хостинг

после переноса сайта на хостинг перестала выводить кириллицу. Место букв выводит вопросительные знаки. 
Вот что в meta

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

На сервере стоит такая же кодировка. Если вывести это сайт через локальный сервер то все выводится корректно.

Comment: Если вывод из Базы Данных, то искать проблему нужно там.

Comment: Если подключится к этой таблицы с локального сервера то все выводит нормально.

Comment: настройки могут быть разными, сервера ведь разные - судя по ответу. Анализируй настройки рабочие, в том числе и копию базы данных, создай такие же настройки на том сервере, откуда идёт вывод. Или обратись к хостерам, чтобы помогли.

Answer (score 2):

Если на локальном всё нормально, то значит у сервера кодировка не UTF-8 стоит. Добавьте в .htaccess `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

И убедитесь что при заливке файлов на хостинг, вы не изменили кодировку кода. Откройте любой файл и посмотрите в какой кодировке он отображается

Comment: Попробовал  добавить текст выведенный не из БД, и он отображается нормально, а текст из БД все также. Но одновременно этот же сайт ,подключающийся с локального сервера к этой же БД,  выводит все нормально.

Comment: `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");  mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");`